# Rotating numbers using modulus

Tags: c#

I have a function (some kind of rotation) for argument `i` in `[1001..999999]` range:

```
 int a = ((i - 1) % (1000000 - 1000) + 1001)
```

As you can see

```
 i = 1001    a = 2001
 ...
 i = 5000    a = 6000
 ...
 i = 999999  a = 1999
```

I want to *inverse* this function, i.e. to have `i = f(a)`, such that if, say, `a = 6000` is given I want to have `5000` as a return etc. Unfortunately, I've experienced a problem with inversing `%` (*modulo operation*). Are there any suggestions in rotating numbers or reversing the above formula?

Comment: What do you mean by *rotate the numbers from 1001 to 999999* . Can you at least show the expected input and output ?

Comment: KISS. Your formula will become too convoluted. Just use a separate variable with initial value of 1001 and reset it when it hits the ceiling. It will also _keep it readable_.

Comment: @aQsu the problem is that i is actually OID from database but I need my number to start from 1001 instead of 1

Comment: So what you want is something like a ring/circular counter that loops over/repeats the range `1001..999999`. But what do you mean by "reversing"? Do you mean making it count backwards, i.e. repeating the range `[999999..1001]`?

Comment: @Abbondanza Yes. Reversing means if i have "a" now and I need to find "i" instead

Comment: So you want to _inverse_, not reverse the function. But how should that be possible? Your function is not bijective, i.e. multiple different values of `i` are mapped to the same `a`. Hence the reprojection of an `a` into the function's domain results in a set of `i`'s rather than a single `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, since `(1000000 - 1000)` is quite *greate* a value, you get for `(i - 1) % (1000000 - 1000)` just *two cases*

```
  i - 1            if i <  999001
  i - 1 - 999001   if i >= 999001
```

And in order to inverse the formula, you have to analyze just these two cases only and you'll get as easy as

```
  if (a > 2000) 
    return a - 1000;
  else 
    return a + 998000;
```

Test

```
  for (int i = 1001; i <= 999999; ++i) {
    // forward, the formula from the question
    int a = ((i - 1) % (1000000 - 1000) + 1001);
    // ...and inverse one
    int r = (a > 2000) ? a - 1000 : a + 998000;

    // do we have reversed value != initial one?
    if (r != i) {
      // this will never happen
      Console.Write("Counter example {0}", i);

      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: ...when you only understand the question after reading the accepted answer. #justStackOverflowThings